# apt-get in download mode

Tags: apt, package-management

From the `man` pages of `apt-get`

```
-d, --download-only
           Download only; package files are only retrieved, not unpacked or installed. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Download-Only.

download
          download will download the given binary package into the current directory.
```

So what is the difference between the following commands:

```
apt-get download apache2

apt-get install --download-only apache2
```

And why the first one gives the following error:

```
Get:1 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 apache2 amd64 2.4.29-1ubuntu4.2 [95,1 kB]
Fetched 95,1 kB in 1s (102 kB/s)                        
W: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file '/home/pkaramol/Desktop/apache2_2.4.29-1ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I didn't manage to figure out the error, the difference in the commands seems to mainly be the following:

```
apt-get download apache2
```

will download just the `.deb` in the current wd

So after the download, running `dpkg -i <filename>.deb` will most likely fail due to missing dependencies

```
apt-get install --download-only apache2
```

will download the respective `.deb` **and** its dependencies under `/var/cache/apt/archives/` where package caching is done;